# How do I get a python program to run in vs code instead of opening in notepad?

Tags: windows-7

I am having some trouble with opening a .py file. I have a program that calls this .py file (i.e. pathname/example.py file.txt), but instead of running the python program, it opens it in Notepad. How do I get it to run?

Answer (score 0):

From Windows File Explorer, right click on the file, then click on `Open with >` in the pop-up menu, and select VS Code in the submenu.

If VS Code does not appear in the submenu, find the binary through `Choose another app`.